# storing string in array

Tags: c

**I have used char *is[] to create array of strings. I have asked user for input of strings. i dont know where I have went wrong. IT IS SHOWING SEGMENTATION FAULT**#include

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int count=0,p;
    char *is[100];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        p=0;
        scanf("%s",is[i]);
        p++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(strcmp(is[i],sis[4+j])==0)
            {
                count=count+1;
            }
        }
    }
    if(count>=2)
    {
        printf("similar");
    }
    else{
        printf("not similar");
    }


}
```

Comment: It's not causing the seg fault but i suspect `p` won't be the value you expect when/if you come to read it.

Comment: The operations on 'p', eg: 'p++;' are redundant.  You continually reset it to 0 anyway.

Comment: Read [ask], please.

Answer (score 2):

`char *is[100];` declares an array of `char` pointers. You need to allocate memory to `is` elements to store string.

```
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    is[i] = malloc(20)  //Assuming each array can hold only 20 chars including null character.
    scanf("%s",is[i]);
}
```